# ASP.NET Core: Matching Routes, One With Body, One Without

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a `DELETE` route that looks like this:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> DeleteService(string id)
{
    return await _repo.DeleteServiceAsync(id);
}
```

I also need to support a `[FromBody]` parameter on this route, which would something like this:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> DeleteService([FromBody] ServiceEntity service, string id)
{
    if(service == null)
        return await _repo.DeleteServiceAsync(id);
    else
        return await _repo.DeleteServiceWithEntityAsync(id, service);
}
```

However, this doesn't work because of [AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.allowemptyinputinbodymodelbinding?view=aspnetcore-2.1), which I do not want to set to true; in every other route/endpoint, the default behavior, `AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding == false`, is desired.

I could have two different routes, one with the body parameter and one without, but that produces matching routes and neither endpoint is hit:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> DeleteService(string id)
{
    return await _repo.DeleteServiceAsync(id);
}

[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> DeleteServiceWithEntity([FromBody] ServiceEntity service, string id)
{
    return await _repo.DeleteServiceWithEntityAsync(id, service);
}
```

What's the best way to get my desired behavior? I'm unable to add a separate endpoint because I need to keep in spec with an existing API.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. Also such "overload" cause misunderstanding in what method really do. As for me, a better solution would be to use another route for deleting with entities method

Comment: I agree - but I'm unable to change the spec. The original API was written using ASP.NET (not Core), which allowed null parameters. I may just have to bite the bullet and set AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding true, but I'm holding out hope for another solution.

Comment: I have a few ideas on this, but have a couple of questions I need to ask before considering posting an answer. 1: Is it a 415 response you get when you don't provide a body? and 2: Have you confirmed that setting `AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding` to `true` actually works?